# I printed pdf file on chrome browser then the printed document is zoomed in. Is it a bug?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, printing, itext

I made a pdf file using iText library. The exported pdf file is attached in this e-mail.

I use setBlendMode function in PdfGState Class for drawing object with transparency.

But when I ONLY print the pdf file on Chrome PDF Reader, the printed document has enlarged resolution.

How to print pdf file to original size on chrome browser?

[image]

Sample PDF: 125.129.124.44/report/hjlee/bad.pdf

Comment: It says you're using FinePrint trial version. Is this in place of the default Chrome print handler? If so: that's where your problem is because Chrome's default is working properly for me.

Comment: Rhyono, Thank you for your comment. I only used FinePrint in order to show you this printed document. It's same as real printed document.

Comment: If that only happens in Chrome, I think it's more likely a Chrome issue.